# Three-colored plane

Tags: analysis, geometry

Let $\Pi$ is cartesian plane with the usual topology. $A, B, C$ are pairwise disjoint subsets $\Pi$, $A\cup B\cup C = \Pi$. Each of these sets is dense in $\Pi$: $\overline{A}=\Pi$, and $\overline{B}=\Pi$, and $\overline{C}=\Pi$. Is it always possible to find a straight line that contains points $a,b,c$ of these sets (for some $a\in A, b\in B, c\in C)$?

It is always possible if one of these sets contains a line segment.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I found the relevant topic here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134475/what-are-interesting-3-colorings-of-the-plane-without-rainbow-lines

Comment: A neat solution (linked the mathoverflow question) is [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/3ColorsBichromaticLines.shtml#solution)  It would be easy to bring in, but is marked copyright.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Nice solution.